# CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout Reverse Scroll

Tags: android, android-design-library, coordinator-layout

I building a chat application and I have a slight problem. My `RecyclerView` is upside down (newest messages at the bottom) and I need that tool bar would hide, when I scroll up, not down (practically reversed hiding behaviour or something).

Is there are any Solutions with `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout` to do that?
 Any tutorials perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You should try extending `ScrollingViewBehavior` and modify it for your needs.
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html)

Then in your xml, set your custom behavior:

```
app:layout_behavior="com.example.MyScrollBehavior"
```

Comment: Instructions  not clear. Made my own Touch listener and ToolbarHider for RecyclerView.